# How do I get employee details if they are earning more than their paylevel?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with employees and all employees has a paylevel according to their experience (calculated from the hire date) but some earn higher because of previous experience. I have two tables employee table (details about employee including their paylevel number) and the paylevel table (details of pay level) 
Years of experience is calculated. My question is get all employees who are earning more than their paylevel says they earn. Everything is connected to a view.

```
SELECT Accountant_Name, Hire_Date, Pay_Level_Name, 'Pay_Level_No'
CONVERT (INT,Experience_in_Years) as 'XP in years'
FROM accountant_view;
```

So how do I see whether the pay level of each employee matches with the salary of that specific pay level number (salary is in the paylevel table) 
I am not sure whether I am asking the in the right way but any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE paylevel
(paylevel_no SMALLINT IDENTITY (1,1),
paylevel_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
annual_pay MONEY NOT NULL,
min_experience CHAR (3) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT paylevel_pk PRIMARY KEY (paylevel_no)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE accountant
(accountant_id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (01, 1),
branch_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
paylevel_no SMALLINT NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
```

Comment: so you are trying to get all those employees having previous experience. Right?

Comment: I am trying to get all users who are earning more than their designated pay level. So yes, I am trying to get users with previous experience but whether the user has previous experience is not in the database. Only the years they have worked for the company is. Thank you.

Comment: can you please give structure of both the tables?

Comment: @WaqasShabbir I did. Sorry that I didn't earlier.

Comment: your tables structure is not clear to me, firstly it didn't gives any current pay of that accountant (employee) and secondly in ACCOUNTANT table, where is the hireDate?

Comment: I am sorry. I have not added the complete structure thinking the question would be larger than it should. But the answer of LogicalMan helped me get the idea and it works. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you provided (and without actual table schemas unfortunately) the following would act as a guide.

The basic premis is that the actual pay an employee earns needs to compared to the expected pay by means of matching the pay levels up in each table:

```
SELECT emp.ID, emp.PayLevel, emp.ActualPay, pl.PayLevel, pl.Pay_Level_Name, pl.ExpectedPay
FROM Employees emp
INNER JOIN Paylevels pl ON pl.PayLevel = emp.PayLevel
WHERE  emp.ActualPay > pl.ExpectedPay
```

Hope this assists

---

Ravinda,
with the updated schema, here is the likely statement you would use. I have surmised that somewhere in the accountant table you have a column with the actual pay value.

```
SELECT ac.accountant_id, ac.first_name, ac.branch_id, pl.paylevel_name, pl.annual_pay, ac.actual_pay
FROM accountant ac
INNER JOIN paylevel pl ON ac.paylevel_no = pl.paylevel_no
WHERE ac.actual_pay > pl.annual_pay
```

Please provide the actual pay column or source so it can be refined better,

Thanks,